# Ajax, post и амперсанд

Tags: javascript, ajax

Задача состоит в том, чтобы передать серверу POST запрос через Ajax. Но проблема возникает если передавать строку с амперсандом. Она обрезается от него. Не могу справиться.

Скрипт:

```js
function XmlHttp()
{
var xmlhttp;
try{xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");}
catch(e)
{
 try {xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");} 
 catch (E) {xmlhttp = false;}
}
if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest!='undefined')
{
 xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
  return xmlhttp;
}
 
function ajax(param)
{
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) req = new XmlHttp();
                method=(!param.method ? "POST" : param.method.toUpperCase());
 
                if(method=="GET")
                {
                               send=null;
                               param.url=param.url+"&ajax=true";
                }
                else
                {
                               send="";
                               for (var i in param.data) send+= i+"="+param.data[i]+"&";
                               send=send+"ajax=true";
                }
 
                req.open(method, param.url, true);
                if(param.statbox)document.getElementById(param.statbox).innerHTML = '<img src="/images/wait.gif" width="100">';
                req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                req.send(send);
                req.onreadystatechange = function()
                {
                               if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) //если ответ положительный
                               {
                                               if(param.success)param.success(req.responseText);
                                               

                                               
                               }
                }
}
```

Форма:

```html
<input type="text" maxlength="100" id="url" name="url" /> <a href="javascript:return false;" onclick="off(); ajax({url:'/serv.php',statbox:'status2',method:'POST',data:{container:document.getElementById('url').value,},success:function(data){document.getElementById('status2').innerHTML=data;}}); return false;"><span>Отправить</span></a>
```

Могут ли быть потенциальные проблемы с другими символами? Через форму передается ссылка.

Comment: "Она обрезается от него." - ??? не хотите ли объяснить, что от чего отрезается?

Comment: Например, если послать на сервер ссылку http://primer.com/?ddd=1&aaa=2, то придет http://primer.com/?ddd=1

Comment: Костыль тоже подойдет

Comment: а использовать готовую библиотеку нельзя?

Comment: Не, я копи-пастом кожу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого есть специальная функция [encodeURI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/xh9be5xc(v=vs.94).aspx). Экранирует не только амперсанд, но и другие "нелегальные" символы.

В вашем случае необходимо экранировать переменную `send`:

```
req.send(encodeURI(send));
```

<sub>PS. Саму переменную `send` лучше бы переименовать, кстати. См., например, https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms229012(v=vs.110).aspx: `✓ DO name fields using a noun, noun phrase, or adjective.` То же самое правило применяется к переменным: send - это глагол, лучше используйте существительное.</sub>

Comment: Это понял, но не могу понять что именно обернуть в эту функцию. Эксперименты ни к чему не привели. Все, что связано с клиентом у меня вызывает ступор.